# TServerSocket on the localhost generates an exception

Tags: c++, linux, thrift

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Here is an example code which works:

```
boost::shared_ptr<TestHandler> handler(new TestHandler());
boost::shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new TestProcessor(handler));
boost::shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket(9090));
boost::shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory());
boost::shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

thriftServerThread = std::thread(&TSimpleServer::serve, TSimpleServer(processor, serverTransport, transportFactory, protocolFactory));
```

I want to use thrift server only within a localhost so I have changed:

```
boost::shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket(9090));
```

to

```
boost::shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket("localhost:9090"));
```

but then I get the exception:

> Thrift: Mon Mar  2 13:28:03 2015 TServerSocket::listen() setsockopt() TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT Operation not supported
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException'
>     what():  Could not set TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT: Operation not supported

What is wrong ? How to fix that ?

**Edit1** 
I have updated thrift and now I get another error:

> Thrift: Tue Mar  3 13:31:40 2015 TServerSocket::listen() PATH 127.0.0.1:9090
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException'
>     what():  Could not bind: Address already in use

Netstat doesn't find that port. What is going on ?

Comment: 1 minute google search gave me this : [link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/thrift-dev/201411.mbox/%3CJIRA.12753475.1415300509000.436473.1415300554219@Atlassian.JIRA%3E)

Comment: ... and this [THRIFT-2803](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2803)

Answer (score 0):

The path string you provide in the constructor of TServerSocket is not meant be used for specifying server address, but instead used for creating [Domain Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket). Therefore the path is the file path to use.